# Count the number of open windows

Tags: macos, spaces, window-manager

Is there a tool to count the number of windows I have open, including on all Spaces?

I am curious and too lazy to do it manually. :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess this AppleScript should do:

```
set numberOfWindows to "0"

tell application "System Events"
    set allProcesses to application processes
    repeat with i from 1 to number of allProcesses
        tell process i
            set numberOfWindows to (numberOfWindows + (count windows))
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Lol: tell app "System Events" to count windows of processes

Comment: @l-ri I made my statement deliberately more verbose, given that other users usually want to incorporate more than just a count of all processes´ windows and thus might learn more this way - but true, your version is shorter. Don´t get how your Lol is supposed to be helpful, though.

Comment: OK, so I paste that into the AppleScript editor and I get: 'error "System Events got an error: Access for assistive devices is disabled."' How do I enable it? For applications that I've installed previously that needed this, the app itself prompts me. "Enable access for assistive devices" is enabled in my system preferences.

Comment: You can check whether it´s enabled by running `tell application "System Events" to get UI elements enabled`. You can enable it by adding `tell application "System Events" to set UI elements enabled to true` in the beginning of the script; though it seems strange for me, that it seems to be already enabled in your case.

Comment: OK, so `tell application "System Events" to get UI elements enabled` returns `true`, but the error above still happens, even with adding the enabler line you suggest to the beginning.